# Show out of stock configurable products without simple products (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, out-of-stock

On the frontend, configurable products (**without** associated simple products) are not displayed on the frontend. `Show out of stock products is set to` YES`. To get them displayed we have to create a simple product. This option we are trying to avoid. Unfortunately, we don't remember how we made it work 2 years ago (Magento 1.6)